# Show the supremum of a set is less than infinity

Tags: general-topology

> Let X be a compact topological space and $<Y,d>$ be a metric space. Show that for every pair of continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X \to Y$, the extended real number $$B=\sup\{d(f(x_1), g(x_2)): x_1,x_2 \in X\} \in [0,\infty]$$ is, in fact, a real number.

I'm a little lost as to what I'm trying to prove.

so, I know that a continuous image of a compact set is compact and thus, f[X] is compact and metrizable because it is a subset of a metric space...I'm not sure where to go from there..or if I'm even on the right track

Comment: You're trying to prove that $$\sup \left\{ d(f(x_1),g(x_2)) : (x_1,x_2) \in X^2 \right\} < \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

I am going to put the answer in a way that I think will be easy to understand:

> Show that the supremum of the set $\{d(f(x_1), g(x_2))\}$ is lesser than $\infty$, (the distance function, i.e., the metric) where $ x_1,x_2 ∈ X$ (or $(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X$).

Comment: I understand that better. I'm not sure where to start. Should I start with the properties that make it a metric space?

Comment: so, I know that a continuous image of a compact set is compact and thus, f[X] is compact and metrizable because it is a subset of a metric space...I'm not sure where to go from there..or if I'm even on the right track